# Is storing XAML in a database bad design?

Tags: c#, xaml, database-design

For example, say that I'm writing an application that allows users to design their own business card, allowing them to add visual objects to the "template" that they are currently designing, each of these objects are bound to various bits of user-data.

eg. They drag an "Address Box" that automatically puts in the address of the user, then a "Name Text" which again, automatically uses the users defined Name.

The reason for this is that a customer may create 15 templates all with their own "look", however if they want to change their address, they only need to modify it in one place.

All of these visual objects and the template itself, are written in XAML. I need to store these user-created templates into the database so that they can retrieve them and edit them later. The way I see it, I have two options:

1. Store the entire template as XAML in a database table called "templates" along with an ID and an OwnerID.
2. Create a table for an abstract type of "visual object". Create a table for each concrete type of visual object (ie. "AddressBox") which would inherit from the abstract type and have fields for each of the user-configurable properties (font size, x/y coords, etc). Finally, create a table called template, which holds a collection of visual objects.

It should be noted that I've been using the Entity Framework to design this, so apologies if I've thrown some EF keywords in there!

Personally, for the time being XAML storage may well be enough to satisfy our requirements, however everything I've seen seems to suggest it's a really bad way to store data in a database.. ie. Skip to 35mins in this: http://youtu.be/uFLRc6y_O3s isn't this exactly what he's suggesting not to do?

With XAML storage I gain property value inheritance, which could potentially make things slightly easier, although I'm not sure if the users will understand how values might "flow" down the chain. Obviously XAML also allows me to store any property value I like; I don't have to add it to the database first.

The downsides are that I think it could be a lot harder to manage the data if it's all XAML; worst case potentially having to retrieve every piece of XAML, parse all of them, find a value I need to change / look at, re-parse, save the updated "blob" of XAML back. This will obviously result in much larger read/write operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for storing the XAML directly. Reason is that the only advantage that you get from storing an abstract layout, is that you could replace the UI framework, and you guard yourself from a potential breaking change in XAML.
But as a breaking change introduced by Microsoft would break all controls out there, so there will be some upgrade possiblity that you quite likely can utilize as well.

For me option 2 is for sure the nicer version, but I tend to be a "YAGNI"-guy. So develop stuff when you need it, and if you are on WPF go for it.

hth,
Martin

Comment: Interesting... This wasn't the response I was expecting at all! What about maintainability? Especially if the types being stored in the XAML aren't plain old CLR objects, they are custom types? Also, if I ever wanted to know how many people are utilizing our "AddressBox" object, doesn't storing it as XAML make it much harder to get that information?

Comment: right now you are given yourself the answer, what you want to do. I just proposed what I would do with the information you have provided. -> which is "keep it simple"

Comment: Well the main reason I asked is that for the time being XAML storage may well be enough to satisfy our requirements, however everything I've seen seems to suggest it's a really bad way to store data in a database.. ie. Skip to 35mins in this: http://youtu.be/uFLRc6y_O3s isn't this exactly what he's suggesting *not* to do?

Comment: I think the point is.. there's no right or wrong answer here. It's about being pragmatic regarding what you're trying to do, or what you hope the application will do in the future.  If storing the XAML is going to create hardships in other areas, you have to weigh that pain before pursuing option 1. If its going to not have a lot of dependencies or needs beyond just providing presentation code, there's probably no harm in storing it via option 1 because you may go through a lot of effort to abstract via option 2 and never gain anything by it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd vote for option 2, though I wonder, if you will need separate tables for each concrete object, instead of having a field for each of the "user-configurable properties" you can put all the user configurable properties in another table linked to the conrete-object table something like.

**ConcreteObjectTable**

ObjectID | ObjectName | ObjectTemplate

---

**ConcreteObjectPropertyTable**

PropertyID | ObjectID | PropertyName | PropertyValue

---

This way you have only 2-3 tables to worry about for configuration options

Answer (score 2):

I'd  vote for option 2 too. By storing it in that way, you are very flexible in the way of using the data.

The downside, option 2 would force you to write some kind of parser, which parses the data to XAML code. But when you want 2 GUI's of the same data (HTML for example), the only thing you have to do is write an HTML parser and youre good to go. Also the data you would save to the database would decrease.

So summarizing (for option 2):

**Pros**

- Flexible interpretation of data
- Lower database space needed for data storage

**Cons**

- You need to write a parser for every GUI implementation